# Move objects around, with gesture recognizer for multiple Objects

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch

I am trying to make an app where you can use Stickers like on Snapchat and Instagram. It fully worked to find a technique, that adds the images, but now I want that if you swipe the object around the object changes its position (I also want to make the scale / rotate function).

My code looks like this:

```
@objc func StickerLaden() {
   for i in 0 ..< alleSticker.count {
        let imageView = UIImageView(image: alleSticker[i])

        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: StickerXScale[i], y:StickerYScale[i], width: StickerScale[i], height: StickerScale[i])

        ImageViewsSticker.append(imageView)
        ImageView.addSubview(imageView)
        imageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true

        let aSelector : Selector = "SlideFunc"
        let slideGesture = UISwipeGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: aSelector)

        imageView.addGestureRecognizer(slideGesture)
    }
}

func SlideFunc(fromPoint:CGPoint, toPoint: CGPoint) {
}
```

Comment: You need a `UIPanGestureRecognizer`. It's explained [here](https://iosdevcenters.blogspot.com/2017/02/uipangesturerecognizer-tutorial-in.html). Scale and rotate are very tricky to get correct; try to find a good tutorial.

Comment: But how can I use it with multiple images because I just want to change the position of the touched object

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the high-level steps you need to take:

- Add one `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to the parent view that has the images on it.
- Implement `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` methods to keep track of the user touching and releasing the screen.
- On first touch, loop through all your images and call `image.frame.contains(touchPoint)`. Add all images that are under the touch point to an array.
- Loop through the list of touched images and calculate the distance of the touch point to the center of the image. Chose the image whose center is closest to the touched point.
- Move the chosen image to the top of the view stack. [You now have selected an image and made it visible.]
- Next, when you receive pan events, change the frame of the chosen image accordingly.
- Once the user releases the screen, reset any state variables you may have, so that you can start again when the next touch is done.

The above will give you a nicely working **pan** solution. It's a good amount of things you need to sort out, but it's not very difficult.

As I said in my comment, **scale** and **rotate** are very tricky. I advise you to forget that for a bit and first implement other parts of your app.

Comment: Thank you really much okay I will Go on with another part and comeback after

Comment: Hey I also have a draw function, which works with touches Moved/begins/endend, and I am not sure how to get the Pan gesture work, when it is active ..., because when I tried to use the gesture it didn't work is there any way to deactivate the touches... , when ... Is not true or sth like this,

Comment: Help pls... @meaning-matters

Comment: @faridorid If you already work with the raw touch events you may have disabled the gesture recognizer. I'd suggest to forget about the gesture recognizer then and use the raw touch event to move your views. I wish we were colleagues and could sit together for half an hour; much easier to than writing things and not seeing what you've done so far. Anyway, I wish you look and let me know if you have more questions.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Hello @meaning-matters as you know the image I want to move is a subview, if I now change stickerXScale/ StickerYScale the image/Sticker doesn't move, is there a Possibility to reload the image?

Comment: so know i have a code to move the object (touches begin....) and now I ask me how to scale/rotate the objects

Comment: @faridorid [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiview/1622459-transform) you read that when you set a transform to a `UIView`, it's `frame` is no longer valid. So I suggest to start with scaling by enlarging your views' frame; not by setting its `transform`. You must process the touch events and recognize when two finger are inside a view. Then when the user drag one or both the fingers you enlarge the frame's view. Try things yourself and when you're stuck post a new question and let me know here in a comment and I'll look. Focus on scaling; forget about rotation for now.